# jQuery: Append string values from forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Bonjour, I am working on a jQuery project with the following scenario:

1/ There are 3 forms on the landing page for user to enter 3 different names.

2/ When user enter a name (`#term1`/`term2`/`term3`) in any of the `#form`, an image associated will appear.

The order of entering the names should not be restricted.

Eg. If user enters "Karen" in one of the forms, the name "Karen" will be printed and an associated image will be printed. If user enter "Baby Kevin", the name "Baby Kevin" will be printed next to "Karen" (ideally with a comma separating the names) and an associated image will be added next to the previous image.

I have encountered a problem where:

1. When a name is being entered, it would print the whole string of all the formsrather than appending it.

   Eg. If I have entered "Wallace" previously, and when I enter "Karen" in another `#form` after, it would print "WallaceWallaceKaren".
2. If I submit the `#form` with the `#button`, the associated image would not show.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#info").hide();

    var displayContent = function () {
        $("#info").show();
        var content1 = $('#term1').val();
        content1 = content1.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
        var content2 = $('#term2').val();
        content2 = content2.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });
        var content3 = $('#term3').val();
        content3 = content3.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });

        var name1 = content1;
        var $nameText1 = $("#name"),
            str = name1;
        html = $.parseHTML(str),
        nodeNames = [];
        $nameText1.append(html);

        var name2 = content2;
        var $nameText2 = $("#name"),
            str = name2;
        html = $.parseHTML(str),
        nodeNames = [];
        $nameText2.append(html);

        var name3 = content3;
        var $nameText3 = $("#name"),
            str = name3;
        html = $.parseHTML(str),
        nodeNames = [];
        $nameText3.append(html);
    }

    $('#search').click(displayContent);
    $('#term1').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            displayContent();
            $('#figure').prepend('<img src = "http://placebear.com/100/100" />');
        }
    });
    $('#term2').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $('#figure').prepend('<img src = "http://placebear.com/80/80" />');
            displayContent();
        }
    });
    $('#term3').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $('#figure').prepend('<img src = "http://placebear.com/50/50" />');
            displayContent();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
#figure {
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="form">
    <section id="fetch">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term1" />
        <button type="button" id="search">OK</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term2" />
        <button type="button" id="search">OK</button>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name here" id="term3" />
        <button type="button" id="search">OK</button>
    </section>
    <section id="info">
        <h4>Take a look inside with:</h4>
        <section id="content">
            <h5 id="name"></div>
            <div id="figure"></div>
        </section>
 </section>
</section>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cklkaren/f9m65to6/)

Comment: I must say your code is a mess.

Comment: i said before i think there is a lot of mistake in you code.... you must clean it before to be abble to perfom something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cleared out your code and its working now. You can give it a try.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#info").hide();
    var displayContent = function(){
        $("#info").show();
        var str = [],
            imgs = ["http://placebear.com/100/100","http://placebear.com/101/101","http://placebear.com/102/102"];
        $("#fetch input[type=text]").each(function(i){
            var v = $(this).val();
            if(v != ""){
                str.push(v.toUpperCase());
                if($("#figure").find("#image_"+i).length == 0){
                    $('#figure').prepend('<img src="' + imgs[i] + '" id="image_'+i+'" />');
                }
           }else{
               $("#figure").find("#image_"+i).remove();
           }
        })
      $("#name").html(str.join(", "));
   }

   $('#search').click(displayContent); 
   $("#fetch input[type=text]").keypress(function(event){       
       if(event.which == 13){
            displayContent();
        }
    });
});
```

Plus your html has some problem `<h5 id="name"></div>` should be `<h5 id="name"></h5>`

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f9m65to6/1/

Comment: Hi @Harry Bomrah, thank you very much for your answer and suggestion:))) If I would like to have different images being displayed according to the form. Eg. To display ImageA if the first form is being submitted and to append ImageC if the last (third) form is being submitted as well; is it possible for me to use `$("#figure").html(img.join());` or something similar please? x

Comment: Merci beaucoup :))) x

Answer (score 1):

Instead of append use $("#term2").val($("#term2").val()+"newValue")